# CakePHP session variable become something else

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm having a problem with CakePHP session.
I already set the session like the following.

```
$this->Session->write('ProjectID',6);
```

but then when I use the following code to read the value, it become something else.In my case, it become 'img'.

```
$this->Session->read('ProjectID');
```

I've try to work with Google on this issue but no one seems to have same problem as I am.

Comment: it might b getting changed somewhere else...

Comment: I already go through the controller and even renaming the variable. But still the same..

Comment: where do you reading the session?

Comment: In controller. I put it in beforeFilter() to test it.

Comment: debug it inside the same action after setting it and check..

Comment: Did it. Sometimes it become 6, sometimes it become img. 6 is the projectid.

Comment: Maybe somewhere the projectID is set to img, try setting with other variable.

Comment: if u use dreamweaver use Find all -> Ctrl+FindAll -> "ProjectID" inside Project folder. Its common sense  that somewhere in your project value is being changed , else it wont change Itself.

Comment: Negative jQuery Angry Bird, its not changed anywhere from project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the Session was not destroyed or the key was removed before you read it. And it is highly recommended that you check if the key really exists before each read, and to use the cakephp dot notation like this:

```
if($this->Session->check('Project.id')) {
    $this->Session->read('Project.id');
}
```

Comment: Hi Pedro, thanks for the reply.

I already do checking before read the session, similar like one your reply, but its not happen also. the session check return true,but the data is always wrong.